# How do I get the Google Account ID when making an authenticated call to a Cloud Endpoints API from an Android app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When making an authenticated call to a Cloud Endpoints API from an Android app, is it possible to get the actual Google Account ID of the person making the call?

I'm asking because I am not getting back the same Account ID: I am getting back a different ID than what I get when the same user logs in with her Google Account directly to my App Engine web application.

This is very confusing. Are the Cloud Endpoints and App Engine User IDs supposed to be different?

(I am trying to identify users in the Datastore by User ID because I understand that, although rare, the User Email can change)

Answer (score 2):

The `userId` provided by `User` class is not the same as the account ID (in fact it's Google+ ID)

You can obtain account ID using like below, where `accountName` is user email.

```
String accountId = GoogleAuthUtil.getAccountId(this, accountName);
```

Send this `accountId` to the server when creating a new user, but I would rather use `userId` as a key for the user kind in your datastore.

Comment: thank you this is a really good hint in the right direction. I am curious why you say you would rather use the `userId` as a key. Do you know if the differences between these IDs are documented anywhere?

Comment: I just tried this and this gives me the same account id that I already had. Ie, the one that is different than what I get back on the App Engine side.

Comment: Because `userId` is provided by `User` it is secure to use. If you would like to use `accountId` you have to either pass it to every endpoint method or obtain it from Google API in your endpoint method implementation. First method is insecure (`accountId` may be easily spoofed), the second method will kill the API quota if you have high traffic. The only reasonable solution to me is use `userId`.